# What is the best website to write or just simply put your feelings and publish it?

Tags: ghostwriter

What I want on that day is to gain knowledge nothing more nothing less and I have it. The people We met in that way gave us an inspirations; being strong, to be loved and felt being a useless.

We help them as much as We can but people will always disappoint us.
We help them to achieve what they wants; encourage them to express their hidden feelings but on the end of the day We still alone.

Walking alone reminds me of the life; you see laughter, painfulness and inspirations. We need to walk firmly, full of pride and with dignity. 
No matter how many rejections you've receive that way you always gain knowledge about it.

Comment: The description here is irrelevant to the title. If that's to 'make up' for the simplicity of the question, don't worry. It's fine to have a simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wattpad?.. there you can read, write and publish your own book.